# Java: serialize external (final) field

Tags: java, serialization, jboss, infinispan

I have a class `PasswordEncryptor` that uses `org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor` as one of its fields, since I am trying to make the app 'clusterable' all classes need to be serializable for session replication, but whenever `PasswordEncryptor` is accessed I run into the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:891)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1063)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:885)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1063)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:885)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:680)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:62)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:119)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.SimpleMarshalledValue.getBytes(SimpleMarshalledValue.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.SimpleMarshalledValue.writeObject(SimpleMarshalledValue.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:175)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1007)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:885)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:62)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:119)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.MarshallUtil.marshallMap(MarshallUtil.java:60)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.MapExternalizer.writeObject(MapExternalizer.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.MapExternalizer.writeObject(MapExternalizer.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.writeObject(ExternalizerTable.java:406)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:145)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:62)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:119)
    at org.infinispan.atomic.AtomicHashMap$Externalizer.writeObject(AtomicHashMap.java:229)
    at org.infinispan.atomic.AtomicHashMap$Externalizer.writeObject(AtomicHashMap.java:226)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.writeObject(ExternalizerTable.java:406)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:145)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:62)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:119)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller.objectToObjectStream(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller.objectToObjectStream(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:151)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.objectToObjectStream(AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.java:44)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.MarshalledValue.serialize0(MarshalledValue.java:119)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field spe
    in field bean
    in object java.util.HashMap@b629b463
    in object org.jboss.as.clustering.SimpleMarshalledValue@b629b463
    in object org.infinispan.util.FastCopyHashMap@43ad73a2
    in object org.infinispan.atomic.AtomicHashMap@4fd181fe
    in object org.infinispan.marshall.MarshalledValue@4fd181fe
    in object org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand@ce32d716
    in object org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand@293098b
```

I have already tried marking the field as `transient` as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor;

public class PasswordEncryptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Need to mark transient as its not serializable
    private transient StrongPasswordEncryptor spe = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();

    public String encrypt(String password){
        return spe.encryptPassword(password);
    }

    public boolean isPasswordCorrect(String enteredPassword, String passwordHash){
        return spe.checkPassword(enteredPassword, passwordHash);
    }

}
```

and I cannot use a wrapper to subclass StrongPasswordEncryptor since it is final

any other ways to do this? (preferably without introducing any other libs)

Comment: You don't have any field in the class except `spe` which is transient. Why do you want to make it serializable anyway?

Comment: Does the following JVM flag provide useful info: -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true

Comment: Also: what is final that stops you doing the serialisation? Only the static serialVersionUID is final in your code, and static fields aren't serialized.

Comment: @Batty - I added transient because spe is not serializable, the reason is in the question

Comment: @AndyTurner StrongPasswordEncryptor is final (the 3rd party lib), I will try the JVM flag and get back to you on that...

Comment: I understand that, but my point is, if you serialize this class, nothing actually gets serialized. Then what's the point? Though you should not get error with this code.

Comment: @Batty yes I see your point I thought that myself as StrongPasswordEncryptor doesnt actually contain any fields....but I am still getting the exception whenever I use this class in my web app so it must be trying the 'serialize' something...I will add some more detail to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an Infinispan perspective, the best way to control how classes are serialized, and in particular when classes are final or you can't modify the class, is to provide your own Infinispan Externalizer for the class you want to serialize. Infinispan's user guide contains a full chapter on [how to Plug Infinispan with User-Defined Externalizers](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_plugging_infinispan_with_user_defined_externalizers) explaining its benefits, which include reduced payloads, faster serialization and gets around issues when classes to be serialized cannot be modified. Apart from the examples in the documentation, the [Infinispan source code (ASL2)](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan) contains plenty of Externalizer examples to achieve what you need.

More specifically, an Externalizer for PasswordEncryptor would not need to write anything in `writeObject` and in `readObject` it'd just need to instantiate PasswordEncryptor.

Comment: Hi Galder, could you provide a link to an example AdvancedExternalizer for 5.2.3Final, the UserGuide covers 5.3 which seems to be a bit different....I have tried browsing https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/tree/5.2.x but cannot find a good example?...thought you could point one out as I saw your name in the source

Comment: There are a few examples in this [test class](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/5.2.x/core/src/test/java/org/infinispan/marshall/AdvancedExternalizerTest.java). That's quite an old Infinispan version btw.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, I was using the version shipped with JBoss AS 7.2.0, would you recommend me using Infinispan 6?

Comment: Wildfly 8 ships Infinispan 6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the field as `transient` as you have already done. Then you have to serialize the single attributes of the class manually. This will look like this:

```
 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os){
   try{
    os.defaultWriteObject();
    os.writeChars(spe.encryptPassword("your password"));
   }
  catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you mark classes transient? I thought the keyword applied only to fields.

Comment: private transient StrongPasswordEncryptor spe = new StrongPasswordEncryptor(); is a field

Comment: Java can do that job(of writeObject) for you, unless you need something specific.

Comment: Yes, in this case we need something specific, isn't it?

Comment: @RenéWinkler Thanks trying this but org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor doesnt have any fields , only 2 methods with args, will that work? http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/util/password/StrongPasswordEncryptor.html

Comment: @RenéWinkler - stupid mistake on my part, I was updating the wrong class...the 'transient' mark worked ok without the need for the writeObject, thanks for looking into this

Comment: Although this is a valid answer, [Infinispan Externalizers](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_plugging_infinispan_with_user_defined_externalizers) offers a much cleaner way to serialize data, without even having the need to touch `PasswordEncryptor` and importantly, allowing `StrongPasswordEncryptor` reference to be final.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a StrongPasswordEncryptor with a zero-argument constructor, you don't need any other data to create it.  It has no state you need to save, so there is no need to serialize it at all.  It's safe to simply re-create it after deserialization.

Marking it `transient` is the correct thing to do.

However, transient fields are null in a deserialized object.

You could provide a `readObject` method as described in [the Serializable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

```
private transient StrongPasswordEncryptor spe = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();

/**
 *  Automatically called when this object is deserialized.
 */
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
throws IOException,
       ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    spe = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
}
```

Another option is to make the field transient and lazily initialize it:

```
private transient StrongPasswordEncryptor spe;

/**
 * Returns this object's StrongPasswordEncryptor, creating it
 * if necessary.
 */
private StrongPasswordEncryptor getEncryptor() {
    if (spe == null) {
        spe = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
    }
    return spe;
}

public String encrypt(String password){
    return getEncryptor().encryptPassword(password);
}

public boolean isPasswordCorrect(String enteredPassword, String passwordHash){
    return getEncryptor().checkPassword(enteredPassword, passwordHash);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, the transient mark on its own works ok, turns out there were two PasswordEncryptor classes in the project and I was only updating one of them, thanks for looking into this